# Connection timeout using standard JSR356 WebSocket client

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, connection, timeout

I have a Java application that connects to a remote websocket server. As a client, I'm using the standard Java EE JSR356 [WebSocket API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/WebSocketContainer.html):

```
javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer.connectToServer(...)
```

However, I haven't found a way to specify a connection timeout using this API. When I call the connectToServer(...) method, it block until it establishes a connection (which may never happen).

Is there a way to specify a connection timeout using the standard API? If not, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not exposed by [JSR 356 - WebSocket API for Java](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356). You will need to use implementation feature, such as [HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.10/org/glassfish/tyrus/client/ClientProperties.html#HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT) in [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net) (reference implementation). Other implementations will most likely have something similar.

Seems like there is no ticket about this yet in [WEBSOCKET_SPEC](https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC), so you can add one if you want (I was able to find only issue which is mentioning SSL properties - [WEBSOCKET_SPEC-210](https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC-210)).

Comment: Tnx for the answer, I created a JIRA issue for this: https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC-234

Answer (score 1):

You can simply override the method connectToServer in WsWebSocketContainer

```
public class WsWebSocketContainer2 extends WsWebSocketContainer {

    @Override
    public Session connectToServer(Object pojo, URI path) throws DeploymentException {
        ClientEndpoint annotation = pojo.getClass().getAnnotation(ClientEndpoint.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            throw new DeploymentException("wsWebSocketContainer.missingAnnotation");
        }

        Endpoint ep = new PojoEndpointClient(pojo, Arrays.asList(annotation.decoders()));

        Class<? extends ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator> configuratorClazz = annotation.configurator();

        ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator configurator = null;
        if (!ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator.class.equals(configuratorClazz)) {
            try {
                configurator = configuratorClazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
            } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
                throw new DeploymentException("wsWebSocketContainer.defaultConfiguratorFail", e);
            }
        }

        ClientEndpointConfig.Builder builder = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create();
        // Avoid NPE when using RI API JAR - see BZ 56343
        if (configurator != null) {
            builder.configurator(configurator);
        }
        ClientEndpointConfig config = builder.decoders(Arrays.asList(annotation.decoders())).encoders(Arrays.asList(annotation.encoders()))
                .preferredSubprotocols(Arrays.asList(annotation.subprotocols())).build();
        Map<String, Object> userProperties = config.getUserProperties();
        userProperties.put(Constants.IO_TIMEOUT_MS_PROPERTY, 999999);
        return connectToServer(ep, config, path);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't ideal, but it does work with this change: the timeout user property value must be a String. `userProperties.put(Constants.IO_TIMEOUT_MS_PROPERTY, "999999");`

Answer (score -2):

Just got this working myself.  If you call connectToServer through a Future construct you can use the timeout in the get() method.

You'll need a ThreadPool:

```
private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

Here's the function:

```
private Future<Session> asyncConnectToServer(Object annotatedEndpointInstance, URI uri) {
        return pool.submit(new Callable<Session>() {
            @Override
            public Session call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
                    return(container.connectToServer(annotatedEndpointInstance, uri));
                } catch (DeploymentException | IOException | IllegalStateException  e) {
                    //throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    return(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is how you call it:

```
 public webSocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI, long timeout) {

        final Future<Session> futureSes = asyncConnectToServer(this, endpointURI);

        try {            
            Session ses = futureSes.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException  e) {
            System.out.println("Time out...");
        }
    }
```

Ref:
https://dzone.com/articles/javautilconcurrentfuture

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).